# How can I setup my local .env files for APP and API

Tags: reactjs, api, heroku

I have cloned an APP and a API github file and I'm following the steps to start it locally, after cloning the repositories the next step is setup your local .env files for app and API.
I would like to know how to set the variables only on my pc in the .env file in a file that has already been set on the computer of other developers and consequently already set variables in the JSON file.

After cloning repository I create .env file in blank and already run npm install and npm start before this his open locally server at localhost:3000 and return an error Error: domain option is required

Comment: Can you provide the link to the repository?

Comment: this repository is not public sorry, but his have a .env file in gitignore, when i clone I don't receive any .env file, so I create one in root file of the project, but I have no idea what I need to put in this file

Comment: @ViniciusCardoso - Another thing you could try as a learning experience is to start a reactjs application from the start just to learn the basics.  Typically .env files are a convention to inject environment variables into an application at runtime to configure it for the host machine.  For example, your error is saying it can't find the domain option, because chances are the react app needs to know what domain it's running on - an example could be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.  You can either search through the code for the error message, or contact the repo owners to explain the .env contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage a package like dotenv by using either npm or yarn to install it.

`npm install --save dotenv`

or

`yarn install --save dotenv`

Create a file in the root of your react application named `.env`

Add your environmental variables to it

```
API_KEY='IAMTHEBESTAPIKEY123'
API_SECRET='SSSSSHHHHHIMASECRET'
```

Then make sure you load the `dotenv` package into your application like so

`require('dotenv').config()`

It sounds like `.env` is already in your `.gitignore`, but if you created this project from scratch you would want to add that

Now you can access environmental variables in your application like so

`process.env.API_KEY`